# Nginx Proxy for Local cache

Tags: nginx

I want to run a local nginx proxy to cache all the responses coming from a remote server.
This should be working but the only outcome I'm getting is a straight redirect from localhost:81 to [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com). What am I missing?

```
proxy_cache_path  /Temp/cache  levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=24h  max_size=1g;

server {
  listen 81;
  listen [::]:81;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://www.stackoverflow.com/;
    proxy_cache            STATIC;
    proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;    
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie Vary;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss what nginx is reverse proxy server, but not proxy server.

If you still want to do this with nginx, you need to take there are more steps. I found instruction on Russian for this
https://habr.com/ru/post/680992/